# As in azure to update database structure, and save the data?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

There is a local and azure database, you need from your local drag the structure to the cloud, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, please see the following article on [Migrating Databases to Azure SQL Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee730904.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)